# Função customizada para a função sorted em python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x, classificação

Em python 2.x eu consigo passar uma função customizada para função sorted, como fazer isso em python 3.x?

Basicamente converter o código abaixo

```
def numeric_compare(x, y):
    return x - y

print(sorted([5, 2, 4, 1, 3], cmp=numeric_compare) )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize o método cmp_to_key da biblioteca functools
Ficará desta forma:

```
import functools
def numeric_compare(x, y):
    return x - y

print(sorted([5, 2, 4, 1, 3], key=functools.cmp_to_key(numeric_compare)))
```

Comment: vlw bro! so corrige o import q ta faltando um s

Comment: Corrigido, que bom que resolveu.